# Python flask array querystring in url_for

Tags: python, flask

I can't find any information about generating a url using array querystrings like so:
http://www.domain.com?page[limit]=20&page[offset]=0

I tried this:

```
url_for(endpoint, page={'limit': 0, 'offset': 0}, _external=True)
```

But it generated the following url:

> http://www.domain.com?page={'limit': 0, 'offset': 0}

My current solution is as follows:

```
querystrings = []
querystrings.append('page[limit]=%d' % (limit))
querystrings.append('page[offset]=%d' % (offset))
url = '%s?%s' % (root_url, '&'.join(querystrings))
```

I really hope there is a better way!

Any help would be appreciated!

---

### Edit

I ended up creating a wrapper which handles the dicts  separately, based on my previous solution:

```
from flask import g, url_for as _url_for

def url_for(endpoint, **values):
    # fix querystring dicts
    querystring_dicts = []
    for key, value in list(values.items()):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for _key, _value in list(value.items()):
                querystring_dicts.append('%s[%s]=%s' % (key, _key, _value))
            values.pop(key)

    # create url
    url = _url_for(endpoint, **values)

    # append querystring dicts
    if querystring_dicts:
        seperator = '?'
        if '?' in url:
            seperator = '&'
        url = '%s%s%s' % (url, seperator, '&'.join(querystring_dicts))

    return url
```

I then call the wrapper like so:

```
url_for(endpoint, page={'limit': 20, 'offset': 0}, _external=True)
```

And it will return the following url:

> http://www.domain.com?page[limit]=20&page[offset]=0

Comment: How is your input stored?

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe what you're attempting is supported out of the box. Under the hood `url_for` is relying on [Werkzeug's URL routing converters](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#builtin-converters) to generate and encode these values and there doesn't appear to be an encoder for dictionaries (minor aside, that is what that `{key: value}` syntax denotes, it's  not an array).

I found [this blurb](https://exploreflask.com/views.html#custom-converters) which outlines the implementation of custom converters if you want to add support yourself. The Flask project may even be happy to get a PR if you go that route, however unless you have some need to use `page[limit]` rather than `page_limit` I would just change them.

```
url_for(endpoint, page_offset = 0, page_limit=0, _external=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up creating a wrapper which converts the dicts to the correct format and then calls the real url_for function. I have added my solution above. Actually, this should really be supported out of the box... I will consider a PR if I get the time!